# TransformTileProvider:No location marker transform specified Unity error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error when I am trying to run a game using a Mapbox prefab: TransformTileProvider: No location marker transform specified.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) Mapbox.Unity.Map.TileProviders.RangeAroundTransformTileProvider:OnInitialized()

If I change OnIntialized to public I get a whole bunch of other errors.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mapbox.Map;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Mapbox.Unity.Map.TileProviders
{
    public class RangeAroundTransformTileProvider : AbstractTileProvider
    {
        [SerializeField] private RangeAroundTransformTileProviderOptions _rangeTileProviderOptions;

        private bool _initialized = false;
        private UnwrappedTileId _currentTile;
        private bool _waitingForTargetTransform = false;

        public override void OnInitialized()
        {
            if (Options != null)
            {
                _rangeTileProviderOptions = (RangeAroundTransformTileProviderOptions)Options;
            }
            else if (_rangeTileProviderOptions == null)
            {
                _rangeTileProviderOptions = new RangeAroundTransformTileProviderOptions();
            }

            if (_rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("TransformTileProvider: No location marker transform specified.");
                _waitingForTargetTransform = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _initialized = true;
            }
            _currentExtent.activeTiles = new HashSet<UnwrappedTileId>();
            _map.OnInitialized += UpdateTileExtent;
            _map.OnUpdated += UpdateTileExtent;
        }

        public override void UpdateTileExtent()
        {
            if (!_initialized) return;

            _currentExtent.activeTiles.Clear();
            _currentTile = TileCover.CoordinateToTileId(_map.WorldToGeoPosition(_rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform.localPosition), _map.AbsoluteZoom);

            for (int x = _currentTile.X - _rangeTileProviderOptions.visibleBuffer; x <= (_currentTile.X + _rangeTileProviderOptions.visibleBuffer); x++)
            {
                for (int y = _currentTile.Y - _rangeTileProviderOptions.visibleBuffer; y <= (_currentTile.Y + _rangeTileProviderOptions.visibleBuffer); y++)
                {
                    _currentExtent.activeTiles.Add(new UnwrappedTileId(_map.AbsoluteZoom, x, y));
                }
            }
            OnExtentChanged();
        }

        public override void UpdateTileProvider()
        {
            if (_waitingForTargetTransform && !_initialized)
            {
                if (_rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform != null)
                {
                    _initialized = true;
                }
            }

            if (_rangeTileProviderOptions != null && _rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform != null && _rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform.hasChanged)
            {
                UpdateTileExtent();
                _rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform.hasChanged = false;
            }
        }

        public override bool Cleanup(UnwrappedTileId tile)
        {
            bool dispose = false;
            dispose = tile.X > _currentTile.X + _rangeTileProviderOptions.disposeBuffer || tile.X < _currentTile.X - _rangeTileProviderOptions.disposeBuffer;
            dispose = dispose || tile.Y > _currentTile.Y + _rangeTileProviderOptions.disposeBuffer || tile.Y < _currentTile.Y - _rangeTileProviderOptions.disposeBuffer;


            return (dispose);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I change it to public, I get these errors: Assets\Mapbox SDK\Mapbox\Unity\Map\TileProviders\RangeAroundTransformTileProvider.cs(15,10): error CS1520: Method must have a return type  AND Assets\Mapbox SDK\Mapbox\Unity\Map\TileProviders\RangeAroundTransformTileProvider.cs(7,15): error CS0534: 'RangeAroundTransformTileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractTileProvider.OnInitialized()'

Comment: The errors from your comment sounds like you made it `public override OnInitialized()` and forgot the `void` return type

Comment: The other one is logged for `_rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform == null` .. when you create a `new RangeAroundTransformTileProviderOptions()` .. where does it get that `targetTransform` from?

Comment: @derhugo Well I found a similar post on this website for someone else having a problem with the TransformTileProvider error and someone commented that instead of public override void for OnInitialized() to change it to just public OnInitialized(). So I tried that it gave me those errors in the previous comment I made.

Comment: And targetTransform comes from another cs file called TransformLocationProvider.cs

Comment: No that was misleading/just wrong unfortunately .. `public OnInitialize()` makes no sense at all ;) it has to be `public override void OnInitialize ()`. What I mean with the second part is: it seems that this `_rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform` she's to be always `null` so either it is never set at all or the other script that should provide this and fill it in already returns `null` itself

Comment: @derHugo Haha yes I knew that didn't make any sense but I was like ok I will try it! I am a little stuck on what to fix. I have tried editing some things in the code above but when I look at some other cs files that pop up in the console with this error they don't show anything about a targetTransform except in that TransformLocationProvider.cs. But in that code targetTransform is equal to value (targetTransform = value;) But it also says a lot of things about location. Do you think I need to set a location that it starts with in code even if I can do that in the inspector in unity? Thanks!

Comment: I would really recommend to [Debug your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) with breakpoints and line-by-line and checkout why exactly the `_rangeTileProviderOptions.targetTransform` is always `null` / why it is never assigned

Comment: @derHugo Following that link you put in the last comment. I already had VS code setup but when I try to change the debug mode (referring to the section in bold "Debugging in the Editor:") where it shows the picture of auto generating light and the little debug image, I don't have that in the bottom right of my unity. Also, in the step under preferences-general-code optimization on startup, that is not an option either. I know this is an issue because when I tried to debug in the console in VS code it didn't do anything.

Comment: I found an article that said it could be that I have to temporarily turn off the firewall on my system and tried it but that didn't help and the debug image in the bottom right of the editor and the code optimization on startup both did not show up. Any ideas on why I could be having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**The camera must be looking at "something" **

Step 1: Abstract Map: General / Extend options: "Range Around Transform".

Step 2: Abstract Map: General / Extend options / Target Transform: "PlayerTarget(Transform)"

Source: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1592263/how-can-i-solve-this-problem-using-mapbox-in-unity.html